# How can I create a array of objects using usestate inside usecontext

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-state, use-context

I can't update my array inside my context.

I've tried with spread and concat, but doesn't work.

Please consider that context are working fine, Also consider that I've tried both filter and find, and both are entering on if consitional, however is not saving a new value to the state.

**My function:**

```
const createChatDetailRegister = async (channelSid: string) => {
const existsChannelInfo = chatDetails.filter(chatInfo => chatInfo.channelSid === channelSid);

if (existsChannelInfo.length < 1) {
  const chatInfo = { channelSid, isChatOpen: true };

  setChatDetails(prevstate => [...prevstate, chatInfo]);
}
```

**My state:**

```
  const [chatDetails, setChatDetails] = useState([]);
```

**My entire context:**

```
import React, { createContext, ReactNode, useState } from 'react';

interface ChatContextData {
  createChatDetailRegister: (channelSid: string) => void;
}

interface ChatProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export const ChatContext = createContext({} as ChatContextData);

export function ChatProvider({ children }: ChatProviderProps) {
  const [chatDetails, setChatDetails] = useState([]);

  const createChatDetailRegister = async (channelSid: string) => {
    const existsChannelInfo = chatDetails.filter(chatInfo => chatInfo.channelSid === channelSid);

    if (existsChannelInfo.length < 1) {
      const chatInfo = { channelSid, isChatOpen: true };

      setChatDetails(prevstate => [...prevstate, chatInfo]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ChatContext.Provider
      value={{
        createChatDetailRegister,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ChatContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

By the way i'm importing the provider in my app file

**App file:**

```
import React from 'react';
import App from 'next/app';

import './app.css';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

import { ChatProvider } from '../components/context/Chat';

class MyApp extends App {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <ChatProvider>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ChatProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

The place where I call my context, **index.tsx:**

```
import { ChatContext } from 'components/context/Chat';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Container, ButtonContainer } from './styles';
import { ProjectMembersChatButtonsProps } from './types';

const ProjectMembersChatButtons: React.FC<ProjectMembersChatButtonsProps> = () => {
  const { createChatDetailRegister } = useContext(ChatContext);

  return (
    <Container>
      <ButtonContainer
        onClick={() => {
          createChatDetailRegister('1279812931');
        }}
      ></ButtonContainer>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default ProjectMembersChatButtons;
```

Comment: Where do you call `createChatDetailRegister`? Could it be that your if condition skiped your setter and thus not updating state? I think using `chatDetails.find()` would better suit your purpose, if you're trying to determin if there's existing record matching `channelSid`.

Comment: I call in this way: `<ButtonContainer onClick={() => createChatDetailRegister(channelSid)}`

Comment: Please update the question and show the component where your createChatDetailRegister action take place as well as your `<App />` component, so we can see your component structure and determin what went wrong.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on a snippet?